# heroku deployment error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My rails application works fine on my local machine, but on heroku it displays this error:

```
2011-03-27T13:21:45-07:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupp
ort-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': /app/app/controll
ers/home_controller.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end (Syntax
Error)
```

What does kEND and $end means?

How can I solve this?

Thanks,

Oded

Edit:

In line 14 in the controller is - `end` .

I'm not missing or have too many - `end` in my code.

Comment: a kEnd is an 'end' or a '}' 

What does line 14 in your controller look like?

Comment: @Joseph Le Brech given that it's not in a string or symbol literal.

Comment: did you install a gem locally and not put it in your gemfile?

Comment: @Joseph Le Brech mabye, why do you think that this is the reason for the problem?

Comment: I've had similar issues with things no working in heroku but they do on live. it's either a gemfile or a missing commit. or the version of a gem for heroku has been changed to remove a vulnerability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. The problem was that there was some Hebrew text in the controller.
The weird thing is that the controller was in utf8.

I guess that heroku can read hebrew.

Answer (score -1):

Check the home controller on line 14 - you're probably missing a `}`, `)`, or an `end` somewhere.

If you can't fix the error, paste some code.